UK Family visit visa process, things required and dos & don'ts
I am applying for a UK standard visitor visa on behalf of my family, four adults and one 7 year old child. I have few questions related visa application, documents required and funds required.
About the 7 year old child application:

Do I have to fill the application through Child Visitor Visa or Standard Visitor Visa?
When filling visa application for 7 year does the child need to have an
email account/ID to create UKVI visa account or one of the parent's email id used for their application will work?
What things I should consider and need to know before filling visa
application for 7 year old?
What documents are required for 7 year old?

As part of Standard Visitor visa application when they ask in the application "How much money do you plan to spend on your trip?"

How much approx. amount I should put? (Note: They all are going to live in my house, they don't need to stay in Hotel.)

Also, Which common documents I should be aware of for all them?

How much I funds are needed to show proof of enough funds during visit to the UK?



Please read the Help files. This is not a discussion forum, and aims at one question per post —  a question that has an answer and doesn't seek opinions or discussion. This question may be closed as being too wide-ranging.

The UK doesn’t have a specific ‘daily subsistence’ rate or publish what finds are ‘enough’. Put the truth - the amount of savings you have (backed up by statements) and the amount you plan to spend. This question is similar to: How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
